# Geolocation not working on iOS with Meteor

Tags: javascript, ios, meteor, geolocation

It's been 5 hours i'm struggling with Meteor.

I want to get `Geolocation.latLng()`. It works perfectly on my browser, I coupled it with GoogleMaps to put a marker on a map. I'm following [this example](http://meteorcapture.com/reactive-geolocation-with-google-maps/) and didn't touch it much.

When I compile on iOS the Geolocation returns weird errors on my simulator (iPhone 6 / iOS 8.3) such as `Geolocation failed : Position retrieval timed out`, sometimes it's another one which's very similar (note : it asks me if i want to share my location when i launch the app, and i accept)

[image: geolocation meteor problem ios]

Sometimes it says it just compiled and I get an old version of my app too.
What's happening ? Is it me or it's really THAT buggy once you try to make a real world project ?

This [to-do list tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app) looked very magic but once you understood how it works and you try something real, it's kind of disappointing ... Sounds very unstable and not ready.

Don't hesitate to tell me if i'm doing something wrong ;)

**UPDATE : i've searched a lot more and i'm now trying to setup differently the `timeout` limit of the geolocation package to avoid this error.
Sadly, i realized `timeout : Infinity` is the default value of the source : sounds like an issue.
Nothing is working so far. If anyone has an idea, let me know on that too ...**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally made it work. First I realized you have to setup the accessRule thank to Lucas's answer but it wasn't enough.

```
// In a mobile-config.js in the project
App.accessRule('*://maps.googleapis.com/*');
```

The iOS Simulator provided by Apple seems to have bugs : the position isn't retrieved correctly, or not at all. It's only working if i set the the `Debug > Location` to `City Ride` ; even `Apple` wasn't working properly on my hand.

If nothing works for you, just try all the possible `Location`, it might be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you define an `accessRule` in your `mobile-config.js`? If not, try this.

```
App.accessRule('*://maps.googleapis.com/*');
```

Comment: `mobile-config.js` ? where is it supposed to be ? i didn't get any details concerning the config of anything ...

Comment: well now i added a config and i can now access the "google maps" module (i see the map) but after a few seconds it goes away and the same error occur :(

Answer (score 1):

Here, clone this sample app I put together a while back:

https://github.com/ffxsam/whats-nearby

It works on desktop as well as mobile. All you have to do is add a `settings.json` and add your Google Places API key in there.

```
{
  "apiKey": "...."
}
```

Comment: this app works pretty well, i'll check it out and see what happens in mobile thanks